# how to programmatically install apk with monodroid

Tags: installation, xamarin.android

I have tried to implement the code in monodroid for this question here 
[Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically),
which deals with how to implement what I want on Android with Java. 
I want to do it with monodroid.

Anyone any idea how I keep getting an error...

```
File apkFile = new File({path to APK});
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

For this line:
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(apkFile), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

Did you try:
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new Java.IO.File("pathToAPK"),
"application/vnd.android.package-archive");